# How Can I Step Debug a 7-liner C++ code in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, debugging

I have been using Visual Studio since Visual Studio 6.0 in 1998. Right now, I have Visual Studio 2017, and for some constraining reason, I have to use the `v100` platform toolset when doing C++. The snippet is below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "proj04\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I put a breakpoint in the `cout`. Breakpoint is now showing in red circle.

I can step-debug into the code if I use the default platform toolset which is `v141`. However, if i switch to `v100`, it won't step debug when I press F5 it will just run all the way and exit.

Comment: F5 is the Run debug command. Have you set a breakpoint at the beginning? F10 is the step and F11 is the step into.

Comment: Of course. I have been using visual studio since the COM / ActiveX days and windows programming.

Comment: Ok. With so much experience you can certainly figure it out then.

Comment: Can you show us where exactly are you clicking to add a breakpoint there... Because if I remember correctly, it is a thin plain strip somewhere behind the line numbers (If you have that enabled that is)...

Comment: I've noticed both VS2015 and VS2017 being reluctant to trace into functions. The nearest thing to a workaround—assuming you are sure that everything is clean and built from scratch after switching libraries—is to put a breakpoint inside the function you want to step into.

Comment: Are you building in Debug mode?  Usually a red circle indicates that 1) the code doesn't exist, 2) there are no symbols for the code.

Comment: It is just the 7-liner above. It is `/FR"Debug\" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\Project4.pch" `

Comment: After turning off incremental linking I was actually able to build with VS2017 (15.8.7) and the toolset v100. I could set a breakpoint (**solid** red circle) on line 5 and then even step inside the `ostream::operator<<(int)` (I had added `<< 1 ` for that purpose), with F11, something that didn't work with toolset v141, even though I seemed to be able to set a breakpoint in the ostream header file. So it works for me, for unknown reasons.

Comment: It takes some kind of `pattern recognition` to smell quirks such as these. Last month, ATL won't work VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

I tested on my other machine with an updated VS2017 version `15.8.5` and I can switch Platform Toolsets `v100` or `v141` and can both step-debug no problem.

Therefore, I think this is a bug in my older VS2017 version `15.7.5` (which I can't update as of the moment due to disk space issue).

In the older VS2017 version `15.7.5`, the workaround I found is to first create the project in VS2010 and only then later opening it up in VS2017 (buggy version 15.7.5) and converting it to `v141` platform toolset.